# How to copy a variable shape nested list to a fixed shape list

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

Basically, I was trying to do padding, padding for variable length inputs.

> **Given**:
>
> Suppose the variable shape list is
>
> ```
> seq = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]],
>        [[1], ],
>        [[7,8,9], [10,11]]]
> ```
>
> The fixed shape list of zeros has a shape of `[3, 2, 4]`
>
> ```
> fixed_list = [[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
>               [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
>               [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> The desired output is a copy from variable shape list to its
>   corresponding dimensions in the fixed shape list
>
> ```
> output = [[[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 6, 7]],
>           [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
>           [[7, 8, 9, 0], [10, 11, 0, 0]]]
> ```

**Is there any recursive way to achieve the copying process?**

Just a small notice: this is just a specific example, can have more other fixed shape, i.e., `[3,2,5,6,7]` or `[3,4]` for some other sequence examples.

**Edited:**

The sequence can also be,

```
seq = [[1,4,5,7],
       [2,8],
       [6,3,2]]

expected_output = [[1,4,5,7],
                   [2,8,0,0],
                   [6,3,2,0]]
```

which has a shape of `[3,4]`, padding is expected to be generalized on this one too.

**Edited:**

Here's my coding of generating `fixed_list` as a response to the comments.

```
def _dfs_max_len(seqs: list, layers: defaultdict, count=0):
    try:
        len_ = len(seqs)
        if len_ > layers[count]:
            layers[count] = len_
        count += 1
    except TypeError:
        return

    for i in range(len_):
        _dfs_max_len(seqs[i], layers, count)

def get_seqs_shape(seqs: list):
    shape = defaultdict(int)
    _dfs_max_len(seqs, shape)

    return list(shape.values()) # won't need `list` for python2 

def zeros_list(shape: list):
    if len(shape) == 1:
        return [0 for _ in range(shape[0])]

    curnt_shape = shape[0]
    sublist = zeros_list(shape[1:])
    return [sublist for _ in range(curnt_shape)]

shape = get_seqs_shape(seq)
zeros = zeros_list(shape)
```

Comment: I am unable to understand how you are generating `fixed_list`. Able to understand `fixed_list` from `fixed_share` as shown in example, but just wondering what will be `fixed_list` if `fixed_shape` would be `[3,2,5,6,7]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are one and a half recursive solutions, the first actually pads with zeros, the second embeds into an existing block of zeros (or other values).

```
import itertools as it

def subdims(L):
    """determine the depth and max dimensions of a nested list"""
    SL = (subdims(S) for S in L if isinstance(S, list))
    return (len(L), *map(max, it.zip_longest(*SL, fillvalue=0)))

def pad(L, dims):
    """zero-pad a nested list to flush faces"""
    d, *sdims = dims
    L = it.chain(L, it.repeat(0, d-len(L))) if L else it.repeat(0, d)
    return list(map(pad, L, it.repeat(sdims)) if sdims else L)

def py_zeros(dims):
    """create an nd block (a nested list) of zeros"""
    d, *sdims = dims
    return [py_zeros(sdims) if sdims else 0 for _ in range(d)]

def embed(L, Z):
    """copy a nested list into another large enough nested list"""
    for i, x in enumerate(L):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            embed(x, Z[i])
        else:
            Z[i] = x
```

Demo:

```
# pad directly or ...
>>> pad(seq, subdims(seq))
[[[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 6, 7]], [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[7, 8, 9, 0], [10, 11, 0, 0]]]
>>> 

# ... create a block of zeros and ...
>>> py_zeros(subdims(seq))
>>> Z = py_zeros(subdims(seq))
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]

# ... copy there
>>> embed(seq, Z)
>>> Z
[[[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 6, 7]], [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[7, 8, 9, 0], [10, 11, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: Could you illustrate a bit, what does the *map mean? What are the arguments we unpacking here?

Comment: @GabrielChu Maybe the quickest explanation is: In a Python shell try `(1, (2, 3))` and then `(1, *(2, 3))`. So in the code we are building a flat tuple combining `len(L)` and the output of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Naive non-recursive solution: try to update each index, break on error. If the shape of `fixed_list` is known ahead of time, can avoid the call to `shape`. Note that this operates inplace on the `fixed_list`.

```
seq = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]], [[1]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]]

fixed_list = [
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
]

from itertools import product


def shape(xs):
    sh = list()
    while type(xs) is list:
        sh.append(len(xs))
        xs = xs[0]

    return sh


def upd(template, content):
    sh = shape(template)
    for ix in product(*map(range, sh)):
        temp = template
        con = content

        for i in ix[:-1]:
            try:
                temp = temp[i]
                con = con[i]
            except:
                break
        else:
            temp[: len(con)] = con[:]


upd(fixed_list, seq)
```